# Integer comparison matcher in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

Let's say `x` should be bigger than `y`. How do I encode this in rspec?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't have RSpec on hand right now to verify, but I think this ought to work:

```
x.should > y
```

Comment: 'should' is deprecated in recent versions, use 'expect(x).to be > y'

Answer (score 41):

Using rspec 2.14 and the expectation syntax, this can be expressed like this:

```
expect(x).to be > y
```

Answer (score 4):

There are another ways to match inequalities:

```
x.should be_greater_than_or_equal_to(y)
x.should be_less_than_or_equal_to(y)
x.should be_greater_than(y)
x.should be_less_than(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

wont this work for you?

```
x.should be > y
```

you could also try a more intuitive testing framework - [Specular](https://github.com/slivu/specular#assertions)

then you can:

```
is?(x) > y
expect(x) > y
check(x) > y
etc.
```

Comment: Not interested if it doesn't support table testing better than rspec.

Comment: sorry? table testing? i'm out of track?

Comment: You throw a bunch of rows of data at the framework and it executes each predicated per row.